# Missing Jbutton row inside Jpanel

Tags: java, swing, layout, jframe, jbutton

Can anyone tell me why the JFrame is missing a row of buttons? I'm trying to make a memory card game where you click on the button and it's replaced by an image but some buttons aren't showing up? I think it has to do with my layout. There should be a 4x4 of clickable jbuttons.

[image]

```
package memoryCard;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class gameBoard {

    public void newGame() throws IOException

    {
        //MAIN FRAMES
        JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("Wagner's Memory");
        mainFrame.setSize (800, 650);
        mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);

        //Buttons
        JButton a1 = new JButton("");
        JButton a2 = new JButton("");
        JButton a3 = new JButton("");
        JButton a4 = new JButton("");
        JButton b1 = new JButton("");
        JButton b2 = new JButton("");
        JButton b3 = new JButton("");
        JButton b4 = new JButton("");
        JButton c1 = new JButton("");
        JButton c2 = new JButton("");
        JButton c3 = new JButton("");
        JButton c4 = new JButton("");
        JButton d1 = new JButton("");
        JButton d2 = new JButton("");
        JButton d3 = new JButton("");
        JButton d4 = new JButton("");

        //images

        //penguin.jpg (a1 & d3)



        //jax.jpg (a2 & c1)

        String pathJ = "jax.jpg";
        File fileJ = new File(pathJ);
        BufferedImage jax = ImageIO.read(fileJ);
        ImageIcon imgJ = new ImageIcon(jax);

        //blink.jpg(a3 & d4)
        String pathB = "blink.jpg";
        File fileB = new File(pathB);
        BufferedImage blink = ImageIO.read(fileB);
        ImageIcon imgB = new ImageIcon(blink);


        //mona.jpg(a4 & c4)
        String pathM = "mona.jpg";
        File fileM = new File(pathM);
        BufferedImage mona = ImageIO.read(fileM);
        ImageIcon imgM = new ImageIcon(mona);

        //beer.jpg(b1 & c2)
        String pathBeer = "beer.jpg";
        File fileBeer = new File(pathBeer);
        BufferedImage beer = ImageIO.read(fileBeer);
        ImageIcon imgBeer = new ImageIcon(beer);

        //jesus.jpg(b2 & c3)
        String pathJes = "jesus.jpg";
        File fileJes = new File(pathJes);
        BufferedImage jesus = ImageIO.read(fileJes);
        ImageIcon imgJes = new ImageIcon(jesus);


        //bball.png(b4 & d2)
        String pathBB = "bball.png";
        File fileBB = new File(pathBB);
        BufferedImage bball = ImageIO.read(fileBB);
        ImageIcon imgBB = new ImageIcon(bball);


        //cullen.jpg(b3 & d1)
        String pathC = "cullen.jpg";
        File fileC = new File(pathC);
        BufferedImage cullen = ImageIO.read(fileC);
        ImageIcon imgC = new ImageIcon(cullen);


        //jpanels

        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel1.add(a1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel2.add(a2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JPanel panel3 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel3.add(a3, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JPanel panel4 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel4.add(a4, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JPanel panel5 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel5.add(b1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JPanel panel6 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel6.add(b2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JPanel panel7 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel7.add(b3, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JPanel panel8 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel8.add(b4, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JPanel panel9 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel9.add(c1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JPanel panel10 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel10.add(c2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JPanel panel11 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel11.add(c3, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JPanel panel12 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel12.add(c4, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JPanel panel13 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel13.add(b1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JPanel panel14 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel14.add(b2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JPanel panel15 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel15.add(b3, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JPanel panel16 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel16.add(b4, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        //CONTAINER & ADDS
        Container content = mainFrame.getContentPane();
        content.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,4));
        content.add(panel1);
        content.add(panel2);
        content.add(panel3);
        content.add(panel4);
        content.add(panel5);
        content.add(panel6);
        content.add(panel7);
        content.add(panel8);
        content.add(panel9);
        content.add(panel10);
        content.add(panel11);
        content.add(panel12);
        content.add(panel13);
        content.add(panel14);
        content.add(panel15);
        content.add(panel16);

        content.setVisible(true);


        //ARRAY
        JButton buttonArray1 [] = {a1, a2, a3, a4,  b1, b2, b3, b4, c1, c2, c3, c4, d1, d2, d3, d4};


        for (int i = 0; i < buttonArray1.length; i++) {
              buttonArray1[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener() { //add an action listener to the current button
               @Override
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
               {
                   int d = 0;
                   d++;

                if (e.getSource() == a1) 
                    {

                        try {
                        String pathP = "penguin.jpg";
                        File fileP = new File(pathP);
                        BufferedImage peng;

                            peng = ImageIO.read(fileP);

                        ImageIcon imgP = new ImageIcon(peng);

                        JLabel imgLabel = new JLabel(imgP);
                        panel2.add(imgLabel);
                        content.add(panel1);
                        panel1.revalidate();
                        panel1.repaint();
                        } catch (IOException e1) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

               }


              });
        }
    }
    public class wtf extends JPanel{
        @Override
       protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

          super.paintComponent(g);

       }
        }
}
```

Comment: for better help sooner post an SSCCE / MCVE, short, runnable, compilable

Comment: There's a lot of useless code, we don't need the images and we don't even have them, please post a [mcve]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A component can only have a single parent.

You try to add your "b" buttons to two different panels, so the buttons are removed from the second panel.

The last panel should display the "d" buttons.

Better yet use a loop to create and display your buttons. Then then game can be any size of grid.

Comment: oh my gosh....what a silly mistake. Thank you! I'm going to try and put them in a loop good idea.